# SSIS with ODBC connection to PostgreSQL fails with connection error

Tags: postgresql, ssis, connection, odbc

I have an SSIS package with Execute SQL Task that connects through ODBC to PostgreSQL DB.
In Visual Stuio 19 it works fine.

But on server with SSIS when I run package from Integration Service Catalog it failing with error:

***Package1:Error: There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.***

***Execute SQL Task:Error: Failed to acquire connection "". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.***

Error goes both when I run in 64 bit and in 32 bit mode.
I tryed run this ODBC connetion from Excel (on the machine where is SSIS installed)  - it works fine.
I tryed make another ODBC connection - to MS SQL server. It runs from the SSIS server fine too.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like permission issue.  Does the account running SSIS/your job have the permissions to the DB?

Comment: Is the error actually `connection ""` or is there a connection name in it? In addition to Brad's thoughts of user/permission, how about networking? Can the SQL Server location's packets get to the PostgreSQL instance?